# Cannot change translate values of existing translation object ngx translate

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm trying to change the value of an object property inside the translation JSON file using ngx translate but the value is not changing, still the same.

I want that when i receive values from API to update it dynamically to the translation object, i tried to use setTranslation() method and set() method but both don't work, when i try to console the value after updating it it's showing Correctly but inside the HTML it's not.

Here is my TS file:

```
getDict() {
    this.getDictionary.getDictionary('dictionary').subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        console.log('ar');
        this.translateService.use('ar').subscribe(response => {
        let config = [];
        for (let i in res) {
        if(res[i].language == 'ar') {
        config[res[i].key] = res[i].value;
        console.log('this is obj ', config);
        this.translateService.get(config[res[i].key]).subscribe((result: 
        String) => {
          console.log('tr res ', result);
          console.log(this.translateService.get(res[i].key));
          this.translateService.set(config[res[i].key], 
          config[res[i].value], 'ar');
        });
       }
       }
     })
    this.translateService.getTranslation('ar').subscribe(res => {
      console.log('this is the language translation ', res);
    });
   }
 )
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div [translate]="'first_name'" [translateParams]="{value: 'world'}"></div>
```

My ar.json file:

```
{
  "admin": {
       "first_name": "{{value}}"
           }
}
```

Note that I reviewed my app module, no issues with it it can read the translation file with no problems at all, I also reviewed the API response, works well without errors and i'm able to return the data from it.

Kindly assist and if you need further information tell me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you have an error in this line:

```
<div [translate]="'first_name'" [translateParams]="{value: 'world'}"></div>
```

It should be:

```
<div [translate]="'admin.first_name'" [translateParams]="{value: 'world'}"></div>
```

But to be honest I don't understand your problem. Can you write in steps what you need?